# How to map form param key with hyphen into Java object field?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a POST request called to my app with Content-Type: **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**.

The Form Data Payload is:
**username=myname%40gmail.com&my-token=dBq26TVjg5jy8Q4kUYyZ2DQ**

I need to map these 2 params into a Java Object:

```
public class MyRequest{
    
    private String username;

    private String myToken;

    //getters setters
}
```

my controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "user/request", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String request(@ModelAttribute(value = "myRequest") MyRequest myRequest, 
Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
```

I see username is populating but myToken is not.

I can't use @JsonProperty("my-token") because it is not a json, what else can be done to get the token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of assigning the value to an object store the value first in a string objects and then store it into the object.

```
public String request(@RequestParam("username") String username,@RequestParam("my-token") String myToken, 
Model model, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
```